# How can I always get to the image on commons instead of the local wiki page?

Tags: wikipedia, mediawiki, wikimedia-commons

If you go to [this article](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutschland) and click on the German flag, you get to

```
https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datei:Flag_of_Germany.svg
```

and a link is presented that bascially says that the original page is in the commons

[image]

When you click on it, you get to

```
https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Flag_of_Germany.svg
```

Is it possible to automatically get to the commons page if the image is on commons (which is not always the case)?

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for an answer specifically for `de.wikipedia.org` then go to the [Gadgets](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spezial:Einstellungen#mw-prefsection-gadgets) section of the preferences and activate the Gadget with the description *"Überspringen der lokalen Dateibeschreibungsseite, um sofort nach Commons zu kommen."* Note that this currently only works if you have [Media Viewer disabled](https://de.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Spezial:Einstellungen#mw-prefsection-rendering-files).

To make this work on any wiki, or with Media Viewer enabled copy the following into your `Common.js`

```
/**
 * Direct imagelinks to Commons
 *
 * Required modules: jquery.mwExtension, mediawiki.util
 *
 * @source www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Snippets/Direct_imagelinks_to_Commons
 * @author Krinkle
 * @version 2014-09-04
 */
if ( mw.config.get( 'wgNamespaceNumber', 0 ) >= 0 ) {
    mw.hook( 'wikipage.content' ).add( function ( $content ) {
        var
            uploadBaseRe = /^\/\/upload\.wikimedia\.org\/wikipedia\/commons/,

            localBasePath = new RegExp( '^' + $.escapeRE( mw.util.getUrl( mw.config.get( 'wgFormattedNamespaces' )['6'] + ':' ) ) ),
            localBaseScript = new RegExp( '^' + $.escapeRE( mw.util.wikiScript() + '?title=' + mw.util.wikiUrlencode( mw.config.get( 'wgFormattedNamespaces' )['6'] + ':' ) ) ),

            commonsBasePath = '//commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:',
            commonsBaseScript = '//commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?title=File:';

        $content.find( 'a.image' ).attr( 'href', function ( i, currVal ) {
            if ( uploadBaseRe.test( $( this ).find( 'img' ).attr( 'src' ) ) ) {
                return currVal
                    .replace( localBasePath, commonsBasePath )
                    .replace( localBaseScript, commonsBaseScript ) +
                    ( /\?/.test( currVal ) ? '&' : '?' ) +
                    'uselang=' + mw.config.get( 'wgUserLanguage' );
            }
        } );
    } );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you need to be logged in. Then go to the following page:

https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Mypage/common.js

and add the following code:

```
jQuery( function() {
    if( typeof( LocalFileLinks ) !== 'undefined' ) { return; }
    jQuery( 'a' ).attr( 'href', function() {
        return this.href
            .replace( '//de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datei:', '//commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:' )
            .replace( '//de.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Datei:', '//commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?title=File:' );
    });
});
```

After that, if you control click images you should go directly to Wikimedia Commons.

Comment: But when you take a look at [the article Diskriminanzanalyse](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diskriminanzanalyse#Gro.C3.9Fe_Intergruppenvarianz), you cannot get to the image page any more as the image [SSWgross.png](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datei:SSWgross.png) is not on commons. Can you fix that?